# Nginx and PHP-FPM on OS X

Tags: php, mac-osx, nginx, operating-system, php-fpm

I've been wanting to try out Nginx with PHP-FPM. I installed Nginx via Macports. I read that PHP 5.3.3 includes PHP-FPM, however, the PHP 5.3.3 configuration on Macports does not enable it.

Can anyone explain or refer me to a tutorial on how to install PHP 5.3.3 with PHP-FPM for Nginx on OS X? I'd want to place it in /opt where Nginx is to keep it away from the PHP I'm using with Apache in /usr/local.

I'm new to command-line stuff. Pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take @Struder's answer above and mostly make it work, but like @Seth I was getting the "cannot stat sapi/cgi/php-cgi" error.

I ended up making some additional tweaks to the Portfile: Adding enable-fpm only when the fastcgi variant is used, getting rid of the "cannot stat" error, and copying the default php-fpm config file into place.  The config file still needs to be user-customized, but this portfile will get you up and running with php5.3.3.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8; mode: tcl; tab-width: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil; c-basic-offset: 4 -*- vim:fenc=utf-8:ft=tcl:et:sw=4:ts=4:sts=4
# $Id: Portfile 71588 2010-09-17 05:21:24Z ryandesign@macports.org $

PortSystem              1.0

name                    php5
conflicts               php5-devel php52
# Update revision of php5-eaccelerator when updating version of php5
epoch                   1
version                 5.3.3
revision                2
set major               [lindex [split ${version} .] 0]
set my_name             php${major}
dist_subdir             ${my_name}
categories              lang php www
maintainers             ryandesign jwa
homepage                http://www.php.net/
master_sites            php
distname                php-${version}
use_bzip2               yes
platforms               darwin freebsd
use_parallel_build      yes

description \
    PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor

long_description \
    PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language \
    that is especially suited for developing web sites, but can also \
    be used for command-line scripting.

checksums \
    [suffix ${distname}] \
    md5     21ceeeb232813c10283a5ca1b4c87b48 \
    sha1    9f66716b341119e4e4f8fe3d81b7d0a5daf3cbc8 \
    rmd160  9edb51663feac9b787f8382012893f1ac98fec6a

depends_build \
    port:pkgconfig \
    port:autoconf213

depends_lib \
    path:bin/gsed:gsed \
    port:libtool \
    port:libxml2 \
    port:bzip2 \
    port:mhash \
    port:pcre \
    port:readline \
    port:zlib

# Use -p1 to accommodate the Suhosin patch
patch.pre_args          -p1
patchfiles              patch-scripts-php-config.in.diff \
                        patch-ext-mysqlnd-mysqlnd.h.diff

use_autoconf            yes
autoconf.cmd            ${prefix}/bin/autoconf213

set phpinidir           ${prefix}/etc/${my_name}
set extraphpinidir      ${prefix}/var/db/${my_name}

destroot.keepdirs       ${destroot}${extraphpinidir}

configure.args \
    --mandir=${prefix}/share/man \
    --infodir=${prefix}/share/info \
    --with-config-file-path=${phpinidir} \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=${extraphpinidir} \
    --disable-all \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --enable-ctype \
    --enable-dom \
    --enable-fileinfo \
    --enable-filter \
    --enable-hash \
    --enable-json \
    --enable-libxml \
    --enable-pdo \
    --enable-phar \
    --enable-session \
    --enable-simplexml \
    --enable-tokenizer \
    --enable-xml \
    --enable-xmlreader \
    --enable-xmlwriter \
    --with-bz2=${prefix} \
    --with-mhash=${prefix} \
    --with-pcre-regex=${prefix} \
    --with-readline=${prefix} \
    --with-libxml-dir=${prefix} \
    --with-zlib=${prefix} \
    --without-pear \
    --disable-cgi

# php5-mysql +mysqlnd needs mysqlnd support compiled into php
configure.env-append    PHP_MYSQLND_ENABLED=yes

configure.universal_args-delete --disable-dependency-tracking

platform darwin 10 {
    configure.env-append \
        LIBS=-lresolv
}

variant no_web conflicts apache apache2 fastcgi description {Don't include any web server support} {}

# Build an Apache 1 module. On Mac OS X, it uses Apple's provided Apache 1 server.
# On other platforms, the MacPorts apache port is used. Keep the options here
# in sync with those in the relevant part of the post-destroot phase.
variant apache conflicts apache2 no_web description {Add Apache 1 web server module} {
    if { ! [variant_isset macosx] && (![info exists os.subplatform] || ${os.subplatform} != "macosx") } {
        depends_lib-append \
            port:apache
        configure.args-append \
            --with-apxs=${prefix}/sbin/apxs
    } else {
        destroot.violate_mtree yes
        configure.args-append \
            --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
    }
}

# Build an Apache 2.2 module. Keep the options here in sync with those in the
# relevant part of the post-destroot phase.
variant apache2 conflicts apache no_web description {Add Apache 2.2 web server module} {
    pre-configure {
        # Checking for mod_cgi.so is a convenient way to verify apache2 is using its
        # +preforkmpm variant. (+eventmpm and +workermpm instead provide mod_cgid.so.)
        if {![file exists ${prefix}/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so]} {
            ui_error "To use ${name} with the +apache2 variant, apache2 must be installed with the +preforkmpm variant."
            return -code error "incompatible apache2 installation"
        }
    }
    destroot.violate_mtree yes
    depends_lib-append \
        port:apache2
    configure.args-append \
        --with-apxs2=${prefix}/apache2/bin/apxs
}

# Build a FastCGI binary. Keep the options here in sync with those in the
# relevant part of the post-destroot phase.
variant fastcgi conflicts no_web description {Add FastCGI web server binary} {
    if { ![variant_isset apache] && ![variant_isset apache2] } {
        configure.args-delete \
            --disable-cgi
        configure.args-append \
            --enable-fpm \
            --enable-cgi
    }
}

foreach {old_variant new_port} {
    gmp             gmp
    imap            imap
    macports_snmp   snmp
    mssql           mssql
    mysql4          mysql
    mysql5          mysql
    mysqlnd         mysql
    oracle          oracle
    pcntl           pcntl
    postgresql82    postgresql
    postgresql83    postgresql
    pspell          pspell
    snmp            snmp
    sockets         sockets
    sqlite          sqlite
    tidy            tidy
} {
    eval [subst {
        variant ${old_variant} description "Obsolete; install ${my_name}-${new_port} port instead" {
            pre-configure {
                ui_msg "The +${old_variant} variant is obsolete. Please install the ${my_name}-${new_port} port instead."
            }
        }
    }]
}

variant ipc description {Add semaphore, shared memory and IPC functions} {
    configure.args-append \
        --enable-shmop \
        --enable-sysvsem \
        --enable-sysvshm \
        --enable-sysvmsg
}

if {![variant_isset apache] && ![variant_isset apache2] && ![variant_isset fastcgi] && ![variant_isset no_web]} {
    default_variants +apache2
}

variant pear description {Add PEAR} {
    configure.args-delete \
        --without-pear
    configure.args-append \
        --with-pear=${prefix}/lib/php
    destroot.target-append \
        install-pear
    destroot.args-append \
        PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=${prefix}/lib/php
    post-destroot {
        #nuke pear-stuff in ${destroot}
        system "cd ${destroot} && rm -rf .channels .depdb .depdblock .filemap .lock"

        system "if \[ -f ${prefix}/lib/php/.depdblock \]; then rm -f ${destroot}${prefix}/lib/php/.depdblock; fi"
        system "if \[ -f ${prefix}/lib/php/.depdb \]; then rm -f ${destroot}${prefix}/lib/php/.depdb; fi"
        system "if \[ -f ${prefix}/lib/php/.filemap \]; then rm -f ${destroot}${prefix}/lib/php/.filemap; fi"
        system "if \[ -f ${prefix}/lib/php/.lock \]; then rm -f ${destroot}${prefix}/lib/php/.lock; fi"
        system "if \[ -d ${prefix}/lib/php/.channels \]; then rm -rf ${destroot}${prefix}/lib/php/.channels; fi"
    }
}

variant suhosin description {Add Suhosin patch} {
    pre-fetch {
        if {"darwin" == ${os.platform} && ${os.major} < 9} {
            ui_error "The suhosin variant requires Mac OS X 10.5 or greater."
            return -code error "incompatible Mac OS X version"
        }
    }
    set suhosin_patch_version   ${version}-0.9.10
    set suhosin_patch           suhosin-patch-${suhosin_patch_version}.patch.gz
    patch_sites-append          http://download.suhosin.org/
    patchfiles-append           ${suhosin_patch}
    checksums-append \
        ${suhosin_patch} \
            md5     b66b27c43b1332400ef8982944c3b95b \
            sha1    76675242cfdeff763767900213346af622002490 \
            rmd160  8dcd8b51ea0357b6cc51e70e495e18f341c62f7c
}

destroot.args \
    INSTALL_ROOT=${destroot}

destroot.target \
    install-cli install-build install-headers install-programs

post-destroot {
    # Copy the Apache 1 module.
    if { [variant_isset apache] } {
        xinstall -m 755 -d ${destroot}${prefix}/libexec/apache \
            ${destroot}${prefix}/etc/apache/extra
        xinstall -m 755 ${worksrcpath}/libs/libphp5.so ${destroot}${prefix}/libexec/apache/
        xinstall -m 755 -c ${filespath}/mod_php.conf ${destroot}$prefix/etc/apache/extra
    }

    # Copy the Apache 2.2 module.
    if { [variant_isset apache2] } {
        xinstall -m 755 -d ${destroot}${prefix}/apache2/modules \
            ${destroot}${prefix}/apache2/conf/extra
        xinstall -m 755 ${worksrcpath}/libs/libphp5.so ${destroot}${prefix}/apache2/modules/
        xinstall -m 755 -c ${filespath}/mod_php.conf ${destroot}${prefix}/apache2/conf/extra
    }

    if { [variant_isset fastcgi] } {
        # If we've built an Apache module (any version) then the FastCGI binary
        # will not have been built, so we need to run through the whole process
        # again and build just the FastCGI binary. Keep the options here in sync
        # with the options specified in the apache and apache2 variants.
        if { [variant_isset apache] } {
            if { ![variant_isset macosx] && (![info exists os.subplatform] || ${os.subplatform} != "macosx") } {
                configure.args-delete \
                    --with-apxs=${prefix}/sbin/apxs
            } else {
                configure.args-delete \
                    --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
            }
        }
        if { [variant_isset apache2] } {
            configure.args-delete \
                --with-apxs2=${prefix}/apache2/bin/apxs
        }

        # Run the build again to get the FastCGI binary. Keep the options here
        # in sync with those in the fastcgi variant.
        if { [variant_isset apache] || [variant_isset apache2] } {
            configure.args-delete \
                --disable-cgi
            configure.args-append \
                --enable-fpm \
                --enable-cgi
            ui_msg "$UI_PREFIX Configuring ${name} again for fastcgi"
            command_exec configure
            ui_msg "$UI_PREFIX Building ${name} again for fastcgi"
            command_exec build
            ui_msg "$UI_PREFIX Staging ${name} fastcgi into destroot"
        }

        # Copy the FastCGI binary to the bin dir under a new name so it doesn't
        # conflict with the cli version.
        if {[file exists ${worksrcpath}/sapi/cgi/php-cgi]} {
            xinstall -m 755 ${worksrcpath}/sapi/cgi/php-cgi ${destroot}${prefix}/bin
        }

        # Copy the default FastCGI config
        xinstall -m 644 ${worksrcpath}/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf ${destroot}${prefix}/etc/
    }

    #file rename ${destroot}${prefix}/etc/pear.conf ${destroot}${prefix}/etc/pear.conf.sample

    # Copy the default php.ini files.
    xinstall -m 755 -d ${destroot}${phpinidir}
    xinstall -m 644 -W ${worksrcpath} \
        php.ini-development \
        php.ini-production \
        ${destroot}${phpinidir}

    # Copy mysqlnd headers.
    xinstall -d ${destroot}${prefix}/include/php/ext/mysqlnd
    eval xinstall -m 644 [glob ${worksrcpath}/ext/mysqlnd/*.h] ${destroot}${prefix}/include/php/ext/mysqlnd
}

pre-activate {
    set filepath ${extraphpinidir}/.turd_${name}
    if {[file exists ${filepath}]} {
        delete ${filepath}
    }
}

post-activate {
    if {[file exists ${prefix}/etc/php.ini] && ![file exists ${phpinidir}/php.ini]} {
        move ${prefix}/etc/php.ini ${phpinidir}
        ui_msg "Your ${prefix}/etc/php.ini has been moved to ${phpinidir}/php.ini"
        ui_msg ""
    }
    if {![file exists ${phpinidir}/php.ini]} {
        ui_msg "To customize php, copy"
        ui_msg "${phpinidir}/php.ini-development (if this is a development server) or"
        ui_msg "${phpinidir}/php.ini-production (if this is a production server) to"
        ui_msg "${phpinidir}/php.ini and then make changes."
    } else {
        ui_msg "You may need to update your php.ini for any changes that have been made"
        ui_msg "in this version of php. Compare ${phpinidir}/php.ini with"
        ui_msg "${phpinidir}/php.ini-development (if this is a development server) or"
        ui_msg "${phpinidir}/php.ini-production (if this is a production server)."
    }

    if {![variant_isset no_web]} {
        ui_msg ""
        ui_msg "If this is your first install, you need to activate PHP in your web server."
        if {![variant_isset fastcgi]} {
            if {[variant_isset apache]} {
                set moduledir ${prefix}/libexec/modules
                set apxs ${prefix}/apache/bin/apxs
            }
            if {[variant_isset apache2]} {
                set moduledir ${prefix}/apache2/modules
                set apxs ${prefix}/apache2/bin/apxs
            }
            ui_msg ""
            ui_msg "To enable PHP in Apache, run"
            ui_msg "  cd ${moduledir}"
            ui_msg "  ${apxs} -a -e -n \"${my_name}\" lib${my_name}.so"
        }
    }

    #ui_msg "* copy  ${prefix}/etc/pear.conf.sample to  ${prefix}/etc/pear.conf"
}

variant debug description {Enable debug support (useful to analyze a PHP-related core dump)} {
    configure.args-append   --enable-debug
}

test.run                yes

livecheck.type          regex
livecheck.url           ${homepage}downloads.php
livecheck.regex         get/php-(5\\.\[0-9.\]+)\\.tar
```

Answer (score 6):

Just did that setup on my MBP with OSX 10.6.5
nginx 0.8.53 + php-fpm (php 5.3.3)

For doing this i used the excellent homebrew package installer instead of macports:

```
brew install nginx
```

Homebrew doesnt include php but there is a [non official "formula"](http://notfornoone.com/2010/07/install-php53-homebrew-snow-leopard/) for it

```
brew install php --with-mysql --with-fpm
```

Then you got both installed, the rest is configuration... that you can find easily on the web.

Answer (score 4):

php-fpm is now officially part of macports.

```
sudo port install php53-fpm
sudo port install php54-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `fastcgi` variant of PHP installed by MacPorts ?

> sudo port install php +fastcgi

**EDIT :** Before doing this, edit the Portfile (in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/lang/php5`) and add the following to the configure.args (line 64, for example) :

```
configure.args \
    --enable-fpm \                  # <- add this line
    --mandir=${prefix}/share/man \
```

Comment: I'm trying this right now.

Comment: adding the line '--enable-fpm \' causes an error.
...

--->  Configuring php5
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed
Log for php5 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_php5/main.log
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>

Comment: I'm thinking this is due to me not having libevent installed.

Comment: After installing libevent the next error in the log was "cannot stat `sapi/cgi/php': No such file or directory".

Comment: @Studer - 
if one has fastcgi then there's no need of php-fpm... right?

Comment: @greenmang0 - No, not right at all. php-fpm is still fastcgi, it's just that the current php fcgi handler is bugged and unstable during high loads. php-fpm is meant as a replacement for the vanilla fcgi handler. As of 5.3.3 it is in core as experimental.

Comment: I ended up figuring out a solution which involved making a few more changes to that portfile.

Comment: @Martin F - Thanks. It's true that current php-fcgi handler is unstable during high loads. I use "supervisord" to prevent php-fcgi from crashing.

Comment: Supervisord doesn't really prevent it, rather it restarts crashed processes so the end result is acceptable to most. It's a valid solution, though, and much better than just starting vanilla PHP-cgi and forgetting about it!